# Windows activation and vs 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

My windows is not activated. So I can't make a application with visual studio 2015. How can I get access of vs 2015 such that I can make a website with c #

Comment: Maybe you'd better activate Windows ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I won't encourage pircay